# What is the proper way to handle dynamic `.apply()` usage in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Consider the [following code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=19&ssc=17&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDyBGAraBvAsAKGtMAKAlKpttgE4CmALgK6kB20ADANzTHQC+78uA9neQBc0CJVIBLOgHNC6LCQo160AIzN2XecD4DhoidIA00SgHdeesZJlF5ZKrQYAmdfM2bMwfqOi8k0AF5oAVM4JAJXTAAzajpgSnF+aGAwEBAAWSoAC14AE1wAW2y84QBrcgBPXiiwxGMAOkawUikIYTA6CoBtAF18YQA3XnFc22w-RC6iyhzcnvqwAAdFkAq+JGNm1sI2DA8MFLTMmbzcAHIwM-xXIA), which defines an object with three methods. Each method takes a different number of arguments, and then the code at the bottom calls one of the methods (dynamically, based on the value of a variable) via `apply()` with an `args` array.

```
class Obj {
  a() {
    return 0; 
  }
  b(one: string) {
    return 1;
  }
  c(one: string, two: string) {
    return 2;
  }
}

const obj = new Obj();

function callMethod(method: keyof Obj, ...args: any[]): void {
  obj[method].apply(obj, args) // Errors
}

callMethod('a');
```

When compiling the above code, TypeScript complains, presumably because the `args` array could have length 0 but the `b()` and `c()` methods require some parameters:

```
The 'this' context of type '(() => number) | ((one: string) => number) | ((one: string, two: string) => number)' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type '(this: Obj) => number'.
  Type '(one: string) => number' is not assignable to type '(this: Obj) => number'.
```

This example illustrates the use case of a JavaScript problem that dynamically calls method names based on the value of some variable.

How can I signal to the type checker that:

- any time I call method `a()` the length of `args` will be 0
- any time I call method `b()` the length of `args` will be 1
- any time I call method `c()` the length will be 2

Or, if someone knows of a better way to solve this, I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: My personal typescript rule is to never use `any`. `any[]` does not statically guarantee you pass a compatible list of arguments. For this particular case you could `type ObjMethodArgs = [];`

Comment: @zerkms In my case I have to use `any[]` because this is being called from a function with rest param. I've updated the question to make that clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Parameters<T>` helper type to extract the function parameters in a generic way:

```
function callMethod<T extends keyof Obj>(
  method: T,
  ...args: Parameters<Obj[T]>
): void {
  (obj[method] as any).apply(obj, args);
}
```

Comment: Btw, is there a way to avoid using an ugly `as any` here?